# Is it possible - clear input field on focus with CakePHP (as opposed to just writing some js)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I realize this seems like an obvious JS type thing - but I'm new to CakePHP, and just wondering if there's some elegant solution to clearing a text input when clicking on it.... like maybe an attribute for the field's array  'clearOnFocus'=>'true' or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [placeholder](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) feature of HTML5:

```
$this->Form->input('example', array('placeholder' => 'Your placeholder text'));
```

Comment: me too.  I just added this to my own application.

Comment: I've been using bits of HTML5 for years now, but had never noticed that one! ++ for working perfectly with cakephp!